# Sharepoint foundation 2013 page becomes blank while processing

Tags: sharepoint

Recently i caught an error, In which my processing page becomes blank,
Ex. when my page test.aspx processing for fetching large data approx 300000 rows. This page becomes blank after approx 100 seconds.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `300000 rows` ?? REALLY ? And no relevant code to show?

Comment: Issue resolved. actually it was issue of Domain server, When i put my system in new domain it works like charm. Thanks